# Backbone.js - difference between this.$(selector) and this.$el.find('selector')

Tags: backbone.js

As per title, what is the difference (if any) in a backbone view between saying:

```
this.$('.foo');
```

and

```
this.$el.find('.foo');
```

They both return the element and appear to scope it to the current view but I've seen examples using both methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The difference is precisely none whatsoever. The method in Backbone source code is declared as:

```
$: function(selector) {
  return this.$el.find(selector);
}
```

Comment: @user1781543, you're welcome. And since I see you're new at Stack Overflow, *welcome*  as well. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, though, so it doesn't hang on the unanswered question list forever.

Comment: And here it is in the annotated source: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-157